# Send Dictionary[String,String] from powershell to the TextTransform.exe

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, powershell, powershell-2.0, css

I Define a Dictionary[String,String] in power-shell like:

```
$Parameter = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String,String]'
$Parameter .Add("EntityName","BaseEntity")
$Parameter .Add("NameSpace","Sample.Core")
```

How can i send this $Parameter to TextTransform.exe wrapper.tt file.And how can I get this $Parameter in wrapper.tt .My wrapper.tt language is C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not hung up on the Dictionary[string, string] you can send parameters to TextTransform.exe with the -a parameter. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126245.aspx).

TextTransform.exe -a !!EntityName!BaseEntity -a !!NameSpace!Sample.Core wrapper.tt

```
<#@template language="c#" hostspecific="true"#>
[<#= this.Host.ResolveParameterValue("", "", "EntityName") #>]
```

Or use the T4 API and write a custom host. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126519%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126579%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).